# PHP - Cron Job is sending occasional cryptic emails to me (shared server)

Tags: php, cron, server

I have two `cron jobs` running on a shared server, with BlueHost. Both of the scripts are in the same directory, and are instantiated with the following commands (note, pathnames changed for security/privacy):

**#1 (Every minute)**

```
* * * * * cd /home1/my_site/public_html/sub_dom/ && /usr/bin/php dir1/dir2/dir3/phpscripts/script1.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and

**#2 (Every minute)**

```
* * * * * cd /home1/my_site/public_html/sub_dom/ && /usr/bin/php dir1/dir2/dir3/phpscripts/script2.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

with the trailing `>/dev/null 2>&1` to prevent an email every minute.

I have had the first script running every minute for weeks, and it has only ever worked exactly as intended.

Today, I uploaded the second script, which is almost identical to the first - basically the same as the first, with a couple additional methods, nothing fancy or dramatically different. I know the script is working, because I can see the database alterations that it is making every minute. I don't have a whole lot of experience with `cron jobs`, but it makes sense that the second script should work with basically an identical script and command.

Like I said, the second script *is* working, but every now and then, I get cryptic emails from one (or both?) of the `cron jobs`. Cryptic to me, anyway.

The full list of emails received since I created the second cron job:

```
8:10am (script #1)
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: line 1: 22616 Bus error    /usr/bin/php dir1/dir2/dir3/phpscripts/script1.php > /dev/null 2>&1

8:33am (script #2)
mount: warning: /var/fake/my_site/var/lib seems to be mounted read-write.

8:46am (script #2)
mount: warning: /var/fake/my_site/var/log seems to be mounted read-write.

10:02am (script #1)
cp: cannot create symbolic link `/var/fake/my_site/etc/./localtime': File exists

10:26am (script #1)
mount: warning: /var/fake/my_site/proc seems to be mounted read-write.

1:38pm (script #2)
mount: /var/fake/my_site/root/dev/pts not mounted already, or bad option

2:22pm (script #1)
mount: warning: /var/fake/my_site/proc seems to be mounted read-write.

2:26pm (script #1)
mount: warning: /var/fake/my_site/root/dev/pts seems to be mounted read-write.

3:31pm (script #1)
mount: /var/fake/my_site/root/dev/pts not mounted already, or bad option

6:40pm (script #2)
cp: cannot create symbolic link `/var/fake/my_site/etc/./hosts': File exists

8:04pm (script #2)
mount: warning: /var/fake/my_site/var/lib seems to be mounted read-write.

9:52pm (script #1)
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: line 1: 30823 Bus error    /usr/bin/php dir1/dir2/dir3/phpscripts/script1.php > /dev/null 2>&1

10:27pm (script #2)
mount: /var/fake/my_site/root/dev/pts not mounted already, or bad option

11:28pm (script #2)
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: line 1:  9241 Bus error    /usr/bin/php dir1/dir2/dir3/phpscripts/script2.php > /dev/null 2>&1

11:44pm (script #2)
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: line 1: 31154 Bus error    /usr/bin/php dir1/dir2/dir3/phpscripts/script2.php > /dev/null 2>&1

12:06am (script #1)
mount: warning: /var/fake/my_site/proc seems to be mounted read-write.

12:44am (script #2)
cp: cannot create symbolic link `/var/fake/my_site/etc/./exim.pl': File exists

12:58am (script #1)
mount: warning: /var/fake/my_site/ramdisk/php seems to be mounted read-write.
```

I have a very limited knowledge of servers, and have only created a couple `cron jobs` in the past. This problem disappears as soon as I remove the second `cron job`.

When I talk to BH tech support, they only suggest upgrading to dedicated hosting, and that it *might* alleviate the issue.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

If the first one is working, you should consider running only the one cron job every minute & calling the php from script2 from script1? or better yet have a cron.php that calls script1.php and script2.php (via require_once)

Comment: By using your `cron.php` suggestion, can I have both `script1.php` *and* `script2.php` running simultaneously, on separate threads? Having to force one to wait until the other is complete isn't ideal.

Comment: @Birrel to do that, you'd need to spin up a new thread, not ideal or usually not possible on a shared server.